# Expectation with square root

Tags: random-variables, expectation

I don't know how to calculate the expectation when there is some square root in the expression. My problem is this: we have three real random variables $X,Y,Z$, independent and with standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$ and we want to calculate
$$E\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(X + Z + \sqrt{X^2 + 4 Y^2 - 2 XZ + Z^2}\right)\right).$$

How can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I need some tight bounds, if possible.

Comment: I have $1.07766$, which is a numerical result given by Mathematica. But I got the following warning: "NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small."

At least, I need to know how much error there is in this approximation.

Comment: Why do you put $X+Z$ in front of your square root? Since $X$ and $Z$ are zero-mean anyway, your expectation is simply $\frac{1}{2}E\left(\sqrt{X^2+4Y^2-2XZ+Z^2}\right)$.

Comment: Yes, I know. The original problem gives me that expression, I just wanted to keep the original setting here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are mutually independent, standard Gaussian.

The expression of your expectation can be simplified.

Let us denote your expectation as $E$.

First, notice that $X$ and $Y$ are zero-mean, so
$$
E = \frac{1}{2}\mathsf{E}\left[\sqrt{X^2 + 4Y^2 - 2XZ + Z^2}\right]
$$

Grouping terms, we have
$$
\begin{align}
E
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathsf{E}\left[\sqrt{4Y^2 + (X-Z)^2}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathsf{E}\left[\sqrt{4Y^2 + (X+Z)^2}\right].
\end{align}
$$
The last equality holds because $Z$ and $-Z$ have the same distribution, due to the fact that the distribution of $Z$ is symmetric around $0$. In addition, since $X$ and $Z$ are independent standard Gaussian, their sum is zero-mean Gaussian with variance $2$. That is, the sum $X+Z$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt{2}X$. Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
E
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathsf{E}\left[\sqrt{4Y^2 + (\sqrt{2}X)^2}\right] \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\mathsf{E}\left[\sqrt{2Y^2 + X^2}\right]
\end{align}
$$
@bobbym has provided a closed-form expression of this expectation computed with Mathematica in terms of an elliptic integral (see below). The way to derive it is as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
E &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\sqrt{2y^2 + x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2} \ \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4\pi}\int_0^\infty\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}r^2\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta} e^{-r^2/2} \ \mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta.
\end{align}
$$
This is obtained by means of the substitution
$$
\begin{align}
x &= r\cos(\theta) \\
y &= r\sin(\theta)
\end{align}
$$
Then you use
$$
\int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-r^2/2} \mathrm{d}r = \sqrt{2\pi}
$$
and the symmetry of the integral over $\theta$ to show
$$
\begin{align}
E
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\sin^2\theta} \,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{\operatorname{E}(-1)}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align}
$$
consistently with what @bobbym computed.

Comment: They are independent indeed, I forgot this detail. Your solution is a nice expression, but can't be that. I made a lot of simulations and the expected value has to be something closer to $1$.

Comment: @jens "That is, the sum X + Z  has the same distribution as 2X" are you sure about that?

Comment: @bobbym You are right, there is a mistake. It should be $\sqrt{2}X$. Note that the sum $X_1+X_2$ of two independent Gaussian variables $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ is distributed as $\mathcal{N}(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$. You can check this by convolving Gaussian distributions, or via characteristic functions. Funnily, there is even a Wikipedia article on this very specific fact. Check it out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Answer (score 4):

@jens

The line should read as

$\begin{align}
E
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathsf{E}\left[\sqrt{4Y^2 + (\sqrt{2}X)^2}\right] \\ \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\mathsf{E}\left[\sqrt{2Y^2 + X^2}\right]
\end{align}$

(I see you have done so.)

Now Mathematica can do the calculation easily and get:

$E=\frac{EllipticE(-1)}{\sqrt{\pi }}\approx 1.0776657899830802$

which agrees with simulations.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected and completed my post.